# Timeline of the hours of status in a line graph android

Tags: android, graph

I am trying to build a line graph some thing like the image shown.

There will be about 4-5 status among the user will be switching and the graph will be showing how long the user has been in each status for the day.

I have searched some graph library like the MPAndroidChart but couldn't achieve this design in particular.

Comment: found my solution in this link https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/178#!description... Was able to bring the result through XYChart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution in [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/178#!description)... Was able to bring the result through XYChart